# How to get log file path from logging after getLogger()

Tags: python, logging

How can I get the path to the log file for a given instance of the python [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) object after calling `getLogger()`?

My python application sets-up logging in the main python script as follows.

```
import loggging

logging.basicConfig(
 filename = '/path/to/log/file.log',
 filemode = 'a',
 format = '%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
 datefmt = '%H:%M:%S',
 level = logging.DEBUG
)

logging.info("===============================================================================")
logging.info( "Starting Application Logging" )
```

Then other scripts in the same app get that logging config with [getLogger()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) as follows

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
logger.info( "Logging Config Imported in Second Script" )
```

In the second script that only gets the logging config with `getLogger()`, I want to know the path to the log file.

How can I determine the full path to the log file after setting-up logging with `getLogger()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filename (if any) of the log file by inspecting the handlers of the root logger and checking its `baseFilename`

#### tl;dr

For example, update your example from this

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
logger.info( "Logging Config Imported in Second Script" )
```

to this

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
logger.info( "Logging Config Imported in Second Script" )

if logger.root.hasHandlers():
   logfile_path = logger.root.handlers[0].baseFilename
   logger.info( "Logging to File " + str(logfile_path) )
```

### Solution

Actually, your instance of logging set by `getLogger()` can be writing to zero or *many* log files.

You can check to see if there are any log files being written-to by using the [`hasHandlers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.hasHandlers) function on the [root logger](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) (named `logger.root`).

```
logger.root.hasHandlers():
```

`hasHandlers()` will return True if there are more than zero [Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers) being used by the logging object.

From there, you can get the list of handlers by iterating through the list of handlers in the root logger with `logger.root.handlers`.

In the example above, we just grab the first handler (the 0th item in the list).

```
logger.root.handlers[0]
```

I didn't find it documented anywhere, but if you [check the code of the logging module's `FileHandler` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e35430bec528dfb1a653cd457ea58b5a08543632/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1152), then you can see it has an instance variable named `baseFilename` with the path to the file for the FileHandler

```
class FileHandler(StreamHandler):
    """
    A handler class which writes formatted logging records to disk files.
    """
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None):
        """
        Open the specified file and use it as the stream for logging.
        """
...
        self.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(filename)
```

[(source)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e35430bec528dfb1a653cd457ea58b5a08543632/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1152)

So just tack-on the instance variable named `baseFilename` to the end of the first file handler, and you get the absolute path to the log file

```
logfile_path = logger.root.handlers[0].baseFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you use addHandler, there you have an example

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s', 
                              '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does this get the path to the log file? It looks like you're setting the path in this script, so of-course you already have the path. The point of the question is to figure out the path to the log file when you don't already know it..